# React native - variables are resetting somehow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, npm, expo

Ok, I'm having a strange situation with `var` and `React.useState()` variables.
Im using this library https://github.com/tongyy/react-native-draggable#readme to set 2 variables -

```
var color1 = '';
var color2 = '';
```

depending on the position of two Draggables. Here are the Draggables:

```
<Draggable x={wp('40%')-(wp('16.5%')/2)} y={wp('45%')} renderSize={isTablet() ? wp('12%') : wp('16.5%')} hasBorder={true} renderColor={'#00000000'} minX={wp('0%')} maxX={wp('100%')} minY={hp('12%')} maxY={hp('40%')} renderText={''} isCircle onDragRelease={(event, gestureState) => ToggleComboColor1(event, gestureState)} onPressIn={() => {setDidDrag1(true);}} />

<Draggable x={wp('60%')-(wp('16.5%')/2)} y={wp('45%')} renderSize={isTablet() ? wp('12%') : wp('16.5%')} hasBorder={true} renderColor={'#00000000'} minX={wp('0%')} maxX={wp('100%')} minY={hp('12%')} maxY={hp('40%')} renderText={''} isCircle onDragRelease={(event, gestureState) => ToggleComboColor2(event, gestureState)} onPressIn={() => {setDidDrag2(true);}} />
```

I've split the onDragRelease functions into 2 to isolate where one of the colors could possibly be being reset. They are identical functions. Here's one for `color2` :

```
const ToggleComboColor2 = (event, gestureState) => {

      color2 = determineDraggableColor(gestureState.moveX, gestureState.moveY);
      console.log('Second: ', color2);

      if (didDrag1 && didDrag2 && color1 != '' && color2 != '') {
        //setCurrentKey("Combo");
        console.log(color1 + " | "+color2);
        setCurrentColorCombo(
          getColorComboItemArray(color1, color2)[0]
        );
        setCurrentKey("Combo");
        setDidDrag1(false);
        setDidDrag2(false);
      }

    }
```

And here is where the color is determined:

```
  const determineDraggableColor = (x,y) => {
      if(x > wp('0%') && x < wp('40%')) //1st third
      {
        if(y > hp('12%') && y < hp('29%'))
        {
            return 'green';
        } else {
            return 'orange';
        }
      } else if (x > wp('40%') && x < wp('62%')) { //2nd third
        if(y >= hp('12%') && y < hp('22%'))
        {
            return 'blue';
        } else if (y > hp('22%') && y < hp('30%'))
        {
            return 'grey';
        }
        else {
            return 'orange';
        }
      } else { //3rd third
        if(y > hp('12%') && y < hp('29%'))
        {
            return 'purple';
        } else {
            return 'crimson';
        }
      }
    }
```

What will happen is, I'll drag 1 Draggable and it will print the correct color for the range. I'll drag the second Draggable, and it will also print the correct color for the range. Then, since both have been dragged (didDrag1 == true and didDrag2 == true), they will print `(color1 + " | "+color2);`

**And one of the variables will sometimes be blank.**

I have no idea how this could be occurring. With React.useState(), the variables aren't even correct - there seems to be a further delay in setting the variable to the color determined.

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: I would DEFINITELY use `useState`.  Otherwise your variables `color1` and `color2` will be re-created on every render and you will lose the previous value.

Comment: @LindaPaiste I didnt know variables are re created every render. Great to know

Answer (score 1):

React states take a time to update. But i'm sure you still should use them to keep your colors.

To check this "time", create a UseEffect function with your state as a dependency.

```
const [myState, setMyState] = useState(false);

const changeState = () => {
   console.log(new Date().getTime());
   setMyState(true);
}

useEffect(() => {
    console.log(new Date().getTime());
    console.log(myState);
}, [myState]);
```

Reference: [State and Lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)

Comment: Will add to this. Stop using var.